# Is there a way to apply different CSS when a page is loaded in the Firefox sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I would like to make a user script or style sheet that reformats certain pages for more optimal viewing in the Firefox sidebar. Is there a way to tell that a page has been loaded in the sidebar? A pure CSS solution would be awesome, but a JavaScript is perfectly acceptable, too.

Comment: maybe, but do you need "sidebar" or just "very narrow page"? The latter can be accomplished with [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Actually for what I need, "very narrow page" would be just fine, so media queries works. If you submit that as an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style pages differently for narrow displays (like a sidebar), you might use [css3 media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).